# Функция приоритета сравнения в качестве аргумента функции сортировки

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Необходимо отсортировать слова в словаре по созданному алфавиту. Если индекс первой буквы слова в массиве алфавита меньше второй буквы, то слово должно стоять раньше.
есть newArray ['z', 'b', 'a']
есть словарь dictionary {"z":[],"a":["abe","azb","aazb"],"e":[],"b":[]}
необходимо отсортировать в соответствии с newArray, т.е. итоговый результат должен быть {"z":[],"a":["azb","abe","aazb"],"e":[],"b":[]}

```js
function sortStr() {
    var dictionary = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('dictArray').innerHTML);
    var dictionaryOrder = {};
    var index = 0;
    for (var property in dictionary) {
        dictionaryOrder[property] = index;
        index++;
    }

    for (var block in dictionary) {
        if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(block)) {
            dictionary[block].sort(function(a, b) {
                if (dictionaryOrder[a] < dictionaryOrder[b]) {
                    return -1;
                }

                if (dictionaryOrder[a] > dictionaryOrder[b]) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });

            document.getElementById('dictArray').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dictionary);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли побуквенно перебрать слова в словаре

```js
function sortStr() {
    var dictionary = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('dictArray').value);
    var dictionaryOrder = {};
    var index = 0;
    for (var property in dictionary) dictionaryOrder[property] = index++;

    for (var block in dictionary) {
      if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(block)) {
        dictionary[block].sort((a, b) => {
          for(let i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); i++) {
            if(a[i] === b[i]) continue;
            else if(dictionaryOrder[a[i]] < dictionaryOrder[b[i]]) return -1;
            else if(dictionaryOrder[a[i]] > dictionaryOrder[b[i]]) return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        });

        document.getElementById('dictArray').value = JSON.stringify(dictionary);
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<textarea onchange="sortStr()" id="dictArray">{"z":[],"a":["abe","azb","aazb", "aaez", "aeb"],"e":[],"b":[]}</textarea>
```